# nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "gop_cache"

Tags: nginx

My nginx configuration is as follows:

```
  rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4000;
        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
            #publish_notify on;
            #on_publish http://localhost/auth.php;

            hls on;
            hls_path /home/hls/test;
            hls_fragment 3s;
            hls_playlist_length 32s;
            meta on;
            gop_cache on;
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this error when reloading:

> nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "gop_cache" in
>   /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:133

and my nginx version is:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.8.1
built by gcc 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-http_ssl_module --add-module=../nginx-rtmp-module-master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your installed `nginx` is not install the `nginx` module `nginx-rtmp-module-master`.

If you installed `nginx` from source code, you need to --add-module=nginx-rtmp-module-master

For example :

```
./configure --add-module=/path/to/nginx-http-flv-module
make
make install
```

[Here is the official description](https://github.com/winshining/nginx-http-flv-module)

Comment: https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module this is for `nginx-rtmp-module`